# Show block on term page if term has no children

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

Is there a way (probably with PHP block viability settings) to only show a view on term pages and only if the term has no child terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered it over [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58691/how-can-i-show-a-flag-link-only-for-the-deepest-terms-for-a-field-with-multipl/71070#71070), Check if taxonomy_get_children($tid) is empty, Then term has no children.